# How to show list of shops which buy one product on opencart product page?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

We are selling a product in several shops. On product page, how to show list of shops which sells this product? And when customer clicks on these shops, it displays this shop's product page. This is same as the following site.

http://www.prisjakt.nu/produkt.php?p=3895089

[image]

Is there any module? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make some `service connection` by WSDL, SOAP, API... with other shops because their stock, prices... are always changing. Other shops must have these `service connection` also and must be willing to give these informations to your shop.

You don't want to administrate these sort of things.

Answer (score 0):

Just use module multimerch marketplace, and for all shops make account. try this way. or use api and parse xml